# CodeIgniter validation of variables / input not coming from form?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Lets assume I have user generated data which is not coming through a form post.
Is there a way I can use/ extend CodeIgnitors form_validation class to validate that data.

eg.

```
<?php
$userData = array('name' => 'tt' , 'city' => 'London' , 'age' => '1200' );
// How can I validate this data using form_validation checks
// like min_length,max_length,and apply some processing
// like trim,xss_clean provided by the same class

?>
```

Comment: may be not related to question's answer..
But may i know : ...then, by which way, this user generated data is coming from user ? if user is not submitting the form ?

Comment: Hi @TechCare99, you may assume that the user is giving data as a json,instead of individual form element, or that this data is some unprocessed data from a database which needs to be sanitized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can via `set_data()` method, Here you go.

```
$this->form_validation->set_data(array(
        'name'    =>  'Full Name',
        'city'    =>  'City',
));

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('age', 'Age', 'trim|required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    echo 'Invalid: ' . validation_errors();
} else {
    echo 'Valid';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the run and set_rule method of the core form validation lib of codeigniter. This how i do it without extending the core :

```
  // Data coming from backbone model  
     $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); 
     $this->config->load('myValidConf/form_validation');
     $non_post = array(
           'foo' => $data['foo']
      );
     $_POST = $non_post; 
     if ($this->form_validation->run('myConfigarray')!== FALSE) {
            echo 'we're ok';
     } else {
         echo validation_errors() ;
     }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: overwriting $_POST seems to be a bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

Might sound like a dirty hack, but you could spoof a form post by setting $_POST data? Say you receive JSON, you could do something like:

```
$json = "...."; //json encoded string
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
    $_POST[$key] => $value;
}

// do form validation as if the data was posted from a form.
```

This is offcourse just a quick fix. You could extend/overwrite parts of the Form_validation library. How I would do it:

- Add a MY_Form_validation.php library, copy paste ALL functions from Form_validation.php that use `$_POST` (`set_rules()`, `run()`, `matches()`)
- Replace all instances of `$_POST` in MY_Form_validation.php with `$this->validate_data`
- Set `$validate_data` to `$_POST` in the constructor.
- Add a function `set_validate_data()` that allows you to overwrite `$this->validate_data`

You will have to use the $_POST array after the data has been validated, if you want to use the cleaned data. If this is unacceptable, also add a function that cleans $this->validate_data and returns an XSS clean array.

Comment: Not a good code. It could be better done by creating a similar lib to validation which works on any array instead of just $_POST

Comment: You asked for a way, I gave you one, you didn't say you didn't want dirty hacks :p I have added a suggestion for better code.