# Posting key value pair as individual data Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am building a function which posts data using Ajax to my Codeigniter controller. The problem is as follows.

Codeigniter requires individual post data (no object) to allow me to fully validate the data. Otherwise, I need to use the validation rules as discrete methods, and some rules, like xss_clean, are not available as discrete methods (see [CI docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference)). I therefore need to send the data in Ajax like this.

```
data: {
    username: username,
    password: password
},
```

I now have an array passed to the post function.

`{'username': $("#username").val(), 'password': $("#password").val()};`

I need to rebuild this array to the Ajax data way above. I tried for loops and the `.each()` function in the Ajax POST function, but this is not working.

Anyone any ideas on how to fix this and allow me to pass an array to the post function, but also allow me to separate this data in order to validate it with Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974043/codeignitor-validation-of-variables-input-not-coming-from-form) question on Stackoverflow. Codeigniter needs POST data to properly validate the data. To validate each piece of data, the data needs to be separated. This is what I tried to achieve with my Ajax POST function. The Ajax POST function posts an array of all the form data, which is **not separated**. With this array, I was unable to validate the data using the Codeigniter rules.

The solution to this problem is not to try separating this data when posted by Ajax, but when the back-end obtains this POST data. The POST data is obtained as an object by the back-end. By looping this POST data in PHP, new POST indices can be declared, as if they were posted directly by the form itself. This sounds a little cryptic, here's the code which may clarify it:

**login.php**(view) - The page containing the form, which posts the data to a function called 'postajax'. This is function containing a basic Ajax post request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        postvalues = {username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val()};
        postajax('Login', postvalues);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Login.php**(controller) - The controller handeling the POST data. To validate the data in this file, the POST data needs to be separated.

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $value){
    $_POST[$key] = $value;
}
```

Now the POST data is separated how Codeigniter expects it, and normal validation can be used for the data. For example, if the data array contained a key-value pair `username => 'Testuser'`, it can be validated like a normal form.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Here's my post.js file with the POST function.

```
function postajax(page, postvalues){
    $("#result").empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: page, 
        data: {
            data: postvalues
        },
        dataType: "text",  
        cache:false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loading").css({ visibility: "visible"});
        },
        success: 
        function(data){
            $("#loading").css({ visibility: "hidden"});
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Wish you would share your javascript because you seem to be making this a lot harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @DFriend I added it to my answer here. Could be that I'm making it harder, but this is the only way in getting it work.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What exactly are you sending as the second argument to `postajax()`?

Comment: @DFriend `postvalues = {username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val()};`

Answer (score 2):

To post the data with the help of Ajax, simplete use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method. As below

```
 data : JSON.stringify({username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val()})
```

It will  turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string

Comment: It does post the data correctly, but not as two individual pieces of data. It posts the data as one string. I want it to post the username as one string and the password as one string, from an array I passed to the post function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have what you need in

```
{'username': $("#username").val(), 'password': $("#password").val()};
```

which I assume would be the value for the `data:` option of the AJAX call.

That object will appear at the server in the `$_POST` array. For example, if the input values are 'A Name' and 'thisisthepassword' then `var_dump($_POST);` will produce

```
array (size=2)
  'username' => string 'A Name' (length=6)
  'password' => string 'thisisthepassword' (length=17)
```

Using CI methods you would access the posted data like this

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
```

JQuery does all the work of converting the object to the proper data structure for posting to the server.

Comment: In my controller, the $this->input->post('username') value is empty. I can print the array, so the data is actually posted. Next to that, this still requires me to use the form validation rules as discrete methods, which I want to avoid.

Comment: So you are certain that `$("#username").val()` is returning a value? What happens if you `var_dump($_POST);` at your controller?

Comment: Then it just shows all the data I posted, so that part is working. I only need to separate both pieces of data so I can validate them with Codeigniter. Isn't it possible with any kind of for loop?

Comment: If the var_dump of `$_POST` shows both pieces of data then you can proceed with `$this->form_validation->run()` without further processing. `form_validation->run()` uses the $_POST array for its purposes. The problem will come after validation because you need to pass the results back to the AJAX `success:` function have have it act accordingly.

Comment: The var dump does show the two pieces of data, but I'm not sure if Codeigniter can do something with the format it's sent to the PHP script. The `$this->input->post()` is therefore still empty.

Comment: If `var_dump($_POST);` isn't showing something like what is in my answer, what exactly is it showing? Every named item in `$_POST` can be accessed with `$this->input->post('name');` e.g. if this is true `$_POST['username'] === "my name";` then  `$this->input->post("username:)` **will** return "\my name".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122266/discussion-between-pat4561-and-dfriend).